# How can I understand the meaning of cut phrase, like this "きみとずっと、はじめを...", in advertisements or movie trailers

Tags: phrases

I often hear cut phrases in movie trailers or I read it in advertisement posters of manga and I can't completely understand their meaning.

For example this phrase; きみとずっと、はじめを. Does this mean "Forever with you, beginning..."?
It doesn't make sense to me. Or does this really not necessarily have to make sense because it's just a trailer?

Comment: Cut phrases must make (enough) sense.  Are you sure きみとずっと、はじめを is what was said?  It makes no sense.  Where did you hear it?  What film?

Comment: Actually it's from a manga. It's written on the cover page.  I forgot to include the ellipses. I's actually "きみとずっと、はじめを..."

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember the exact trailer where I've heard it. I usually watch variety shows that has no subtitle, like VS Arashi, Bistro SMAP, J-Drama, to practice my listening skills. This videos has a drama or movie trailers at the end. I was wrong for indicating that I often hear it, when in fact I just had the notion that I've heard it as well in a trailer.

Comment: @Karen88 In most trailing sentences, the verb can be more or less guessed because you would be able to see where the sentence is headed.. However, I can't think of what is trying to be conveyed in your example (Googling the exact phrase only brought me back here), as I can't think of a full sentence that starts like that and would make sense. I believe any native speaker would be just as confused as you are. Are you sure you did not mishear the last part? That is usually the vital clue to the continuing verb.

Comment: I'm sorry. But that's all that is written in the cover page of the manga. However, the content of the story, from what I understand from what I read, is this.

Comment: The female MC is bothered that she and her boyfriend are becoming like mature couples, after a year and a half of being in the relationship. This was brought by a survey in a magazine shown by her friend. The survey said that the 2nd year of a relationship is dangerous. And at this stage, usually, couples get bored with one another because of always doing the same old things for too long. To cut the long story short the female MC realized at the end that there are still a lot of "first” that she and her boyfriend can do. So at the end the female MC said: I want to give all my "firsts" to him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have not misheard it, grammatically, some verb is omitted after を because を is the object marker. So it says "I _____ the beginning with you, forever."

Without a bit more context, this catchphrase does not make much sense. But this will make perfect sense as the catchphrase of [*One Week Friends*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Week_Friends), for example, where the memory of the main character lasts only for a week and she has to experience the beginning (of a romantic relationship) again and again. In this case, the missing verb would be something like 体験する or 繰り返す. Actually when I saw 「きみとずっと、はじめを」 I instantly recalled this title because [its live-action film version](http://ichifure.jp/) was released last month. Well, its actual catchphrase was 何度でも君を思い出す, though.

Comment: The catchphrase was actually from the cover page of the manga entitled "たった3文字のきみともキスナ". Would "Forever with you, all my "firsts"..." be an appropriate equivalent if the story goes this way.

Comment: The female MC is bothered that she and her boyfriend are becoming like mature couples, after a year and a half of being in the relationship. This was brought by a survey in a magazine shown by her friend. The survey said that the 2nd year of a relationship is dangerous. And at this stage, usually, couples get bored with one another because of always doing the same old things for too long. To cut the long story short the female MC realized at the end that there are still a lot of "first” that she and her boyfriend can do. So at the end the female MC said: I want to give all my "firsts" to him.